# Saving output from external command!

Tags: command-line, perl, output

I'm not really how to ask this question the right way without being long winded, but will do my best!
I need a script I'm writing to run pidstat -V inside of it and then to capture the output from it and use it to continue the script! I have tried so many variations, the only way I get no error readout is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

       my $cmd = "pidstat -V";
        my @output = `$cmd`;
        chomp @output;


        if (@output eq 'sysstat version 11.2.0 (C) Sebastien Godard (sysstat <at> orange.fr)') {
```

etc etc etc.

The rest of the script runs fine when I use STDIN and the user defines their pidstat version, but when I use the above I get no errors and just a new line! I have come across different pidstat versions which give different readouts so have written my script to fit around this! 
I know I'm missing something but not sure what.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3854742/2072269

Comment: Thank you muru, I ran across this question before, I have tried all the variants to call on pidstat, but I either get "sysstat -V not found", just a new line or sh: 1: sysstat: not found
                                sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected
when I use qx{}.

Comment: If you get `sysstat: not found`, then check if it is installed and in your `PATH`.

Comment: And it looks looks [there is no command named `sysstat` in the repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sysstat&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

Comment: Yeah it's there I have version 11.2.0, it's the first version I used my script on! Colour me confused!!

Comment: Isn't the issue that you are testing an array against a string? shouldn't it be  something like `if ($output[0] eq 'whatever') { . . . }`

Comment: I was really hoping that it was something that simple that I had missed, but still just gives me a new line when i run the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

It was painfully simple, all I needed was to add "2>&1 | sed -e '2d'" to the line:- "my $cmd = qx{pidstat -V};" and delete "(C) Sebastien Godard (sysstat  orange.fr)" from my if statement.

Thanks all for the pointers, they really have helped.